# Disposing a timer inside a ViewModel, upon closing the main window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, timer, mvvm-light

Currently in my application, I have a `RelayCommand` which calls an action which starts a `Timer`. I have a separate command which the calls the `Dispose()` method to get rid of/release the timer. This all sits in the ViewModel counterpart of the project.

Using the MVVM pattern, how would I dispose of this `Timer` upon closing the window, as well as carrying out the regular/default operation of closing the window?

I am also using the MVVM-Light toolkit, if this is of any help.

An example of my current solution is shown below:

### ViewModel

```
private static Timer dispatchTimer;

public MainViewModel()
{
    this.StartTimerCommand = new RelayCommand(this.StartTimerAction);
    this.StopTimerCommand = new RelayCommand(this.StopTimerAction);
}

public RelayCommand StartTimerCommand { get; private set; }
public RelayCommand StopTimerCommand { get; private set; }

private void StartTimerAction()
{
    dispatchTimer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(this.IgnoreThis), null, 0, 15);
}

private void StopTimerAction()
{
    dispatchTimer.Dispose();
}
```

### View (xaml)

```
....
Height="896"
Width="1109"
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid"
          Width="Auto"
          Height="Auto">              
          <Button x:Name="startTimerButton"
                  Content="Start Timer"
                  Command="{Binding StartTimerCommand}"/>
           <Button x:Name="stopTimerButton"
                   Content="Stop Timer"
                   Command="{Binding StopTimerCommand}"/>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

### View (Code-Behind)

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    //Would a 'Closing +=' event be called here?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing the windows may or may not dispose your viewmodel, depending how you register it. One approach would be bind to the Loaded/Unloaded events from the view and do the work there:

**View:**

> xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PageLoadedCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unloaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PageUnLoadedCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public RelayCommand PageUnLoadedCommand { get; private set; }
...
 PageUnLoadedCommand = new RelayCommand(() => OnPageUnLoadedCommand());
```

...

```
    private void OnPageUnLoadedCommand()
    {
        //Unsubscribe and dispose here
    }
```

Comment: I already have this `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`, which I am assuming is the same as what you posted. Will give this a go now. Cheers.

Comment: It's not the same, "i" is just a name I gave it, use a different one if that's already used.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a destructor for your `ViewModel` like below

```
~public MainViewModel()
{
   dispatchTimer.Dispose();
}
```